# Memory zone limits on ARM Linux architecture

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

I have two questions related to ARM Linux memory management:

With the x86, the zones are the following:
ZONE DMA First 16MiB of memory
ZONE NORMAL 16MiB - 896MiB
ZONE HIGHMEM 896 MiB - End

1. What are the zone limits for ARM Linux architecture ? Please limit the doscussion to ARM32 bit... not 64 or LPAE etc.
   As per my understanding only ZONE_NORMAL is the only zone present with 32 bit ARM systems. Is this correct ?
2. Second question relates to 
   https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/arm/memory.txt
   ARM Linux memory map references memory from PAGE_OFFSET to high_memory-1 as Kernel direct-mapped RAM region.
   If there's no highmem in ARm linux ARCH why does we refer to it ?

Comment: Why do you think there is no highmem in arm Linux?

Comment: Part 2 is a one-to-one virtual to physical mapping; ie, the pages are continuous virtually and physically.  The physical pages maybe aliased to other virtual addresses.  This allows a simple subtract/add to convert from a kernel physical to virtual address and vice-versa.

Comment: What are the data structures which contain various zone ranges ? I intend to print them out or use jtag to connect and find out on ARM boards ?